# Query for selecting same or similar data from different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have doc_no, I need to find out its type. So I need to select a query from the table.

```
    SELECT o.type_id
      FROM operation_out o 
    WHERE o.doc_no = 17025337;
```

But what to do, if I have 3 different tables

> operation_out, operation_in, operation_reverse

and given doc_no can be in any of the given tables.

I have already tried union:

```
SELECT transfer_type_id
  FROM (SELECT doc_no, mt_o.type_id
          FROM mt_operation_out mt_o
        UNION ALL
        SELECT doc_no, mt_in.type_id
          FROM mt_operation_in mt_in
        UNION ALL
        SELECT doc_no, mt_r.type_id
          FROM mt_operation_reverse mt_r)
 WHERE doc_no = 17025337;
```

Is there another alternative way of writing this? Is there any syntax in SQL for this kind of task?

- Thank you all for your recommendations. In the end, I created a view based on the `UNION ALL`, and I'm going to use it wherever needed.

Comment: Often, needing to do such a thing on three tables is a sign of a poor data model.  So, the alternative way is to fix the data model so similar data is all stored in one table.

Comment: Welp, I understand what you mean. And that's exactly what I would like to do... But, sometimes I don't have either much of a choice or say in the matters )

Comment: you better use union all and not union, though, depending on your version, the optimizer may handle the thing for you. union will force a sort to return unique rows, while union all won't

Comment: What bothers you with this notation? If it is too long, then you can use a view. If it is too slow, maybe u can create an index for all tables and use union all as recommended. We need to know what is the problem with  this query...

Comment: @KemalKaplan nothing much really. But I wanted to know if there was a more _correct_ way of doing it.

Comment: @gsalem yeah, you are right, I totally forgot **union all**. I just thought, they all would be unique, but there still can be some duplicate doc_no in the given tables

Comment: If you need to search 3 tables you have no option to avoid reading them. `UNION ALL` is the most lightweight operation in this case.

Comment: Is it possible that there would be a different type in the three tables?  If so you may end up with a `TOO_MANY_ROWS` (`ORA-01422`) exception if you are doing a `SELECT INTO`  (Or just in general if it is in more than one table and you use `UNION ALL`)

Comment: using Table SQL Macro? (21c)

Comment: @loic That's the first time me hearing that command, and from what I read, that's an only new addition to the oracle, so I can't use it for earlier editions. We are using **Oracle Database 18c**, so I don't think that will help my case.